# Trying to do a simple JSON Request in Objective-C (IOS7)

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection

I've search and try many different solutions but without luck.

I am trying to make a JSON Request to my server, it works for sure because I've tested it in PHP (simple call, it receives string name and string password and check into the database if the user is correct). The request should receive back a JSON with property "success" only (which could be "true" or "false").

Here is my code:

```
- (void)logonService:(NSString *) name widthArg2:(NSString *) password {
// Create the request.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://46.51.169.145/ios/index.php/user/login/"]];

// Specify that it will be a POST request
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

//setting json fields
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//prepare output data
NSString *in1;
NSDictionary *outputData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:in1, @"success", nil];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonOutputData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:outputData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonOutputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonOutputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//set json string to body data
NSData *requestInputBodyData = [jsonOutputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody: requestInputBodyData];

//prepare input data
NSString *input = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&name=%@&password=%@",name,password];
//Encode the post string using NSASCIIStringEncoding and also the post string you need to send in NSData format.
NSData *inputData = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
//calculate length of post data
NSString *inputLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[inputData length]];
//Set HTTP header field with length of the post data.
[request setValue:inputLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
//encode type
//[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
//add it to http body
[request setHTTPBody:inputData];

// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(conn){
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
}
```

}

The delegate DidReceiveData fires correctly but the result is always NIL:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
NSString *jsonResponseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"RESULT1: %@", jsonResponseData);
[_responseData appendData:data];
```

}

Thank you, hope someone can help me!

Comment: See that "error:" parm?  It's there for a reason.  Use it.

Comment: (And please make it clear, is "data" null, or is "jsonResponseData" null?)

Comment: (And why are you trying to parse the partial result from the server vs waiting for the whole thing?)

Comment: Remove all JSON stuff and get the download working.  When you have it working, put the JSON parsing back into connectionDidFinishLoading, not didReceiveData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks a lot for the comments, I finally fix it, and after that I decided to starting using a JSON library --> https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

This is how I finally have the code:

```
//prepare connection
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@user.php", _urlServer]];
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[data setObject:@"login" forKey:@"action"];
[data setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
[data setObject:password forKey:@"password"];

//start connection
// Create the request, if there is a connection going on just cancel it.
[_connection cancel];

//initialize new mutable data
NSMutableData *receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
_receivedData = receivedData;

//initialize the url which will be fetched
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

//set http method
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//initialize a post data
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] init];
for(id key in data) {
    id value = [data objectForKey:key];
    //keys string
    NSString *newData =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", key, value];
    dataString = [dataString stringByAppendingString: newData];
}

//set request content type we MUST set this value.
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//set post data of request
[request setHTTPBody:[dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//initialize a connection from request
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
_connection = connection;

//NSLog(@"Sending request with parameters: %@", dataString);

//begin the connection
[_connection start];
```

And its working like a charm. Next step is to authenticate somehow, right now connection is open to the world.